# Prove that a group of order $np^m$ has at most one subgroup of order $p^m$ (without Sylow)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elementary-number-theory

This question was taken from Contemporary Abstract Algebra, Joseph A. Gallian (10th edition), Q51 of Chapter 7.

> Prove that a group of order $np^m$ where $p$ is prime and $n<p^m$ has at most one subgroup of order $p^m$.

This question is unusually hard to prove, as opposed to other problems in the same book.

Here is my working on a weaker version of the problem.

> Claim: A group of order $np$, where $p$ is a prime and $n<p$, has at most one subgroup of order $p$. 
> Proof: Let $G$ be a group of order $np$, and suppose $H,K$ are subgroups of G with order $p$. 
> $H\cap K$ is a subgroup of $H$, by Lagrange's Theorem, $|H\cap K|=1$ or $p$. 
> $|H\cap K|$ can't be 1, else $|HK|=\frac{|H||K|}{|H\cap K|}=p^2>np=|G|$, a contradiction. 
> Then we must have $|H\cap K|=p$, which implies $H=K$, so there is only one subgroup of order $p$ in $G$.

Note: Sylow Theorems are not allowed to be used. 
Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I like how you tackled a slightly different problem.

Comment: Can $p$ divide $n$, or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have access to a copy of Gallian, so I cannot check, but the claim is false as stated.

Consider the group $G=S_3\times C_2$ of order $12=3\cdot2^2$, $3<2^2$. We see easily that $G$ has three subgroups of order four.

Answer (score 0):

The clam is true if the condition $n<p^m$ is replaced by $n<p$, which could be a typo. And the way to prove it is how you dealt with the weaker version.